# Create a library of AS3 components for Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, components

I am looking to build a set of components for Flash that our developers can use throughout future projects.

The components are not covered by the standard set of Flash UI components and I don;t think I need to really extend the UI Interface. Instead I would like to be able to distribute a library of FLA (non-compiled) components so that a developer/designer can simply drag a component out of the Library and then edit it however they wish.

I am struggling to work out the best way to achieve this. What is a good way of achieving this? Maintaining the ability to edit components is import, and this would be too limited if it meant creating skins or only changing things programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want your components available for older versions of Flash (CS3 and under), you may want to consider looking into compiling your components into a SWC file.

I remember doing some way back, had to compile each components into its own SWC file but maybe there's a way now just to distribute a package of components in one file - and have them showing up in the library (uneditable components basically).

Don't know of any links off hand though but some googling around the subject of "SWC Components" should give you some useful results.

Comment: Thanks for your response bigp. Unfortunatley I am after "FLA (non-compiled) components" rather thank SWCs as I would like my developers to be able to edit the actual component without limiting them to editing skins etc.